# How to bind dynamic data with input fields using ngModel

Tags: html, angular

I have a dynamic list that has some input and select fields and with those fields, I want to bind dynamic data. I tried binding with ngModel but it only shows the entry from the last object. This is the data which I want to bind

```
properties=[
   {
    "Id": "01",
    "PropertyType": null,
    "PropertyTypeId": 1,
    "PropertyName": "Name",
    "AdditionalList": []
  },
  {
    "Id": "02",
    "PropertyType": null,
    "PropertyTypeId": 1,
    "PropertyName": "Phone",
    "AdditionalList": []
  },
  {
    "Id": "03",
    "PropertyType": null,
    "PropertyTypeId": 1,
    "PropertyName": "Work Phone",
    "AdditionalList": []
  }]
```

The expected output should be like this[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have a look at ngFor at https://angular.io/. Also, strongly typed models in Angular.

Comment: @r2018 thanks but can you a specific link.

Comment: @P.Dederer has given example of its usage in answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  propertyTypes= [
    { id: 1, name: "List" },
    { id: 2, name: "Text" },
  ];
selectedValue = null;
```

This how you could bind the selected value

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (click)="showSelected()">
  <option *ngFor="let c of propertyTypes" [ngValue]="c.type">
    {{ c.type }}
  </option>
</select>
```

And here is a hint how you could process the selected for the with the showselected method

```
 showSelected(item) {
    console.log(this.selectedValue);
  }
```

Comment: Okay.. that's correct but how I set data in input fields.

Comment: I tried this -                                                                
<form [formGroup]="userForm" *ngFor="let row of buildArr(properties);let i = index">
<div class="row" *ngFor="let property of row" >
  <div class="col-sm-3 pl-3">
  <input name="propertyName"  formControlName="propertyName" [(ngModel)]="property.PropertyName">
  </div>
</div>
</form>

Comment: You are mxing up the reactive and template driven approach. Either go with [(ngModel)]  (template) or formControlName (reactive). Delete for example formControlName and add property in component property.PropertyName. That's it. You are already setting your PropertyName to the value of the input

Comment: Thanks, @P.Dederer I found the solution. I bind the data using formControlName and I m setting value from the component like this,                                                     getFormGroupForUserProperty(userProperty: any): FormGroup {
      return new FormGroup({
        propertyName: new FormControl(userProperty.PropertyName),
        propertyType: new FormControl(userProperty.PropertyTypeId),
        parentProperty: new FormControl(userProperty.ParentHierarchyPropertyId),
        readOnly: new FormControl(userProperty.IsReadOnly)  
      });
    }